# Missing assemblies after migrating Silverlight 4 application to visual studio 2013 Silverlight 5

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, visual-studio-2013, .net-assembly, .net-framework-version

We are migrating a Silverlight4 application developed in visual studio 2010 with active directory single sign on to Silverlight 5 for visual studio 2013.

After replacing some .dll's like toolkit and data visualization toolkit and other dll  without changing the framework(4.0) it was working fine but When I am changing the active directory project framework from 3.5 to 4.0 or higher it is throwing the following errors:

```
Error   71  The type name 'RoleProvider' could not be found. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Consider adding a reference to that assembly.    
Error   73  The type name 'MembershipUser' could not be found. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Consider adding a reference to that assembly.  
Error   74  The type name 'MembershipUser' could not be found. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Consider adding a reference to that assembly.  
Error   75  The type name 'MembershipUser' could not be found. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Consider adding a reference to that assembly.  
Error   76  The type name 'MembershipUser' could not be found. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Consider adding a reference to that assembly.  
Error   78  The type name 'MembershipUser' could not be found. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Consider adding a reference to that assembly.  
Error   77  The type name 'MembershipCreateStatus' could not be found. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Consider adding a reference to that assembly.
Error   72  The type 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
```

I tried replacing the assemblies and namespaces but no luck. Does anyone came across this kind of issues. I would appreciate your help if you could give me a solution. thank you very much

Comment: I think you need to remove the existing reference to 'System.Web.ApplicationServices' and refer 'System.Web.ApplicationServices' with version 4.0.0.0.. or higher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the existing reference to `System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll` and refer `System.Web.ApplicationServices` with version 4.0.0.0.. or higher

You can find it in a folder that might look like `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319`